# Есть ли какие-нибудь интересные и понятные книги по математической статистике для data science (Машинное обучение)?

Tags: машинное-обучение

Решился изучить Data Science. Точнее заняться машинным обучением. Но возникают трудности с математикой, в частности с математической статистикой. Вроде очень простая наука, но не для меня. Не могли бы накидать каких-нибудь книжек или статей, по которым может научиться даже ребёнок?

Comment: Тоби Сегаран «Программируем коллективный разум»

Comment: 1) Какой возраст всё же у ребёнка? 7 лет, 11 и 15 - всё же разница очень велика.  2) Какой уровень знания математитки? 3) Отмечу, что математическая статистика никак не является "очень простой наукой". Что такое  умозаключение породило?